# import database internal server error

Tags: drupal, mamp-pro

I want to import Drupal 8 database from webshared hoster to my localhost. But it is not working. I got the message

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, you@example.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

I really have no idea why. Can anybody help?

This is the mysql_error.log

```
160813 10:29:40 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: Normal shutdown
160813 10:29:40 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
160813 10:29:40  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160813 10:29:41  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 128598230
160813 10:29:41 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

160813 10:29:41 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended

160813 10:29:43 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql
160813 10:29:43 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql/ is case insensitive

160813 10:29:43 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
160813 10:29:43 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160813 10:29:43 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160813 10:29:43 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160813 10:29:43 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160813 10:29:43 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160813 10:29:43 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160813 10:29:43  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
160813 10:29:44 InnoDB: 5.5.42 started; log sequence number 128598230
160813 10:29:46 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
160813 10:29:46 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.42'  socket: '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 0  Source distribution
```